# It went well again

Tags: english-to-german, meaning-in-context

Can the phrase "es läuft wieder gut" be an equivalent to "It went well" in german as in this context ?

> Ich hatte erst mal Angst davor, aber nach ein paar Trainings läuft es wieder gut, und es hat wirklich viel Spaß gemacht.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ No I meant the perfekt tense, but you have already gave the answer, thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

> Can the phrase "es läuft wieder gut" be an equivalent to "It went well" in german as in this context ?

No, it can't.

> "It went well"

is translated as

> es ist gut gelaufen

oder

> es hat gut geklappt

while

> läuft es wieder gut,

means that the *well* state was reistablished from a former *illness* or *failure*.

---

In response to your now changed title

> #### It went well again

Would be translated as

> > Es ist **wieder** (mal) gut gelaufen

or

> > Es hat **wieder** (mal) gut geklappt

---

There was a recent phrase

> > "Läuft bei Dir"

elected as ["Jugendwort des Jahres"](http://www.spiegel.de/lebenundlernen/schule/langenscheidt-laeuft-bei-dir-ist-jugendwort-des-jahres-a-1004562.html)

and you probably shouldn't confuse all that at all.

Comment: Or, as they sometimes even say: "Löppt". <g>

Comment: Haben die Zitate in den Zitaten in deinen Posts eigentlich irgendeine tiefere Bedeutung, die ich übersehe?

Comment: @idmean Nein, warum?